# error: libhdf5.so - build error because of hdf5 in Heroku app

Tags: python, heroku, hdf5

I have successfully managed to deploy my python code along with one of my ML-models via a Flask app using Heroku. My second model makes use of the [OpenL3](https://github.com/marl/openl3) package. It works fine on my local machine, but unfortunately it depends on hdf5 and I can not figure out, how to install hdf5 on heroku.

I have tried using unofficial buildpacks, like [this](https://github.com/brondle/heroku-buildpack-python-hdf5) and [this](https://github.com/arnfred/heroku-buildpack-python-hdf5), which did try to install heroku with changes in the compile file, but both are over 4 years old and did not work for me.

I have tried install different hdf5 packages as I would on my local Ubuntu with an Aptfile, but that did not work either.

This is my Aptfile (have tried with and withoud pkg-config):

```
libsndfile1
libsndfile-dev
pkg-config libhdf5-dev
pkg-config libhdf5-serial-dev
pkg-config python3-h5py
pkg-config cython3
ffmpeg
```

and this is my requirement .txt:

```
Flask==2.0.2
librosa==0.8.1
hdf5
openl3
numpy==1.20.3
PyWavelets==1.2.0
scipy==1.7.3
SoundFile==0.10.3.post1
sklearn
gunicorn
```

Others had the same issue while trying to use pytables, but I have not yet found a working solution.
This is the build error:

```
copying h5py/tests/test_vds/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/h5py/tests/test_vds
copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_highlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/h5py/tests/test_vds
copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/h5py/tests/test_vds
copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/h5py/tests/test_vds
running build_ext
Loading library to get version: libhdf5.so
error: libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```